# Loading view in UINavigationController that only appears for a given subview and disappears for others

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview

My application consists of a tabbar controller with several tabs, each with a navigation controller in them. One of these nav controllers contains a table populated via a web service. I'd like to have an overlay on the table (or a different view) that says the service is not reachable if it isn't reachable. However, I only want this overlay on the table, and not on other tabs.

What is the best way to do this? My current solution is a [loading view](http://buildmobile.com/all-purpose-loading-view-for-ios/) that appears for the table when it appears, or when there is a change in reachability and this loading view disappears on viewdiddissapear. I like being able to put a semi-transparent loading view on top of the table so you can see the old data I guess....

Are there better/alternate ways to do this?

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is using an activity indicator with a transparent background.
Here is a complete tutorial and sample code (from Jeff LaMarche).

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010_02_01_archive.html